# What is the difference between .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) and .setIsDesignedForFamilies(true) in android

Tags: android

I want to include some ads in my child app and I came across to the following examples

```
final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setIsDesignedForFamilies(true)
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But what is the difference between those two? It has to do with memory?

Answer (score 0):

By applying .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) tag, you application will display the Adds related children.